# Moving cursor in C using atmega16

Tags: c, cursor, atmega16

We're trying to make a project using atmega 16 and C language. The problem is that whenever we want to move a cursor, it goes to random places instead of moving one character right/left. 
Our first idea was just
`LCD_command(0x10);` 
for going left. It didn't work although we are sure it should (turning off the cursor works in the same function). We also tried:

```
uint8_t position = 0;
[...]
void whichButton(){
whatsPressed = keybord();
switch (whatsPressed):
case 1:
{
position = position + 1; 
GoToXY (position, 0);
}
case 2:
{
position = position - 1;
GoToXY (position, 0); //for going left
}
}
```

Has anybody got any idea how to move it?

Comment: How is `GoToXY()` currently implemented?

Comment: Here you go. http://extremeelectronics.co.in/avr-tutorials/using-lcd-module-with-avrs/

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `atmega`, however, the usual method of getting special keys, like the arrow buttons, is to change to `raw` input rather than `cooked` input and comparing to the keyboard `scancodes`.